# Pythonic application of method decorators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I'm trying to understand how to write a decorator which checks the main_val attribute for every method, especially when the position of the main_val attribute could change, or even have a default. Separately, is there a more pythonic way to apply this condition?

I wrote an example below to visually describe the problem, hoping someone with more experience can shed light.

For each method below, main_val should be the only attribute my decorator should be checking. I'm not sure how force the decorator to always check main_val, unless it's passed as a key=value attribute or refers to hardcoded the position in *args.

```
class TestCase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.allowable_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

    def decorator_check(func):
        # I want to apply condition to "main_val" attribute of any method this decorator is applied to
        def wrapper(self, val, *args, **kwargs):
            if val not in self.allowable_list:
                raise AttributeError("value {} not in allowable list {}".format(val, self.allowable_list))
        return func(self, val, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

    @decorator_check
    def calc(self, main_val, val_num_two, val_num_three):
        print("(calc) - main_val: {} val_num_two: {} val_num_three: {}".format(main_val, val_num_two, val_num_three))
        return main_val * val_num_two * val_num_three

    @decorator_check
    def calc_two(self, another_val, main_val,  val_num_two):
        print("(calc_two) - another_val: {} main_val: {} val_num_two: {}".format(another_val, main_val, val_num_two))
        return another_val * main_val * val_num_two

    @decorator_check
    def calc_three(self, another_val, val_num_two, main_val=3):
        print("(calc_two) - another_val: {} main_val: {} val_num_two: {}".format(another_val, main_val, val_num_two))
        return another_val * val_num_two * main_val

test_obj = TestCase()
```

---

```
test_obj.calc(100, 2 ,3)
```

Returns error as expected

```
test_obj.calc_two(2, 5, 3)
```

Returns (calc_two) - another_val: 2 main_val: 5 val_num_two: 3

```
test_obj.calc_three(2,5,100)
```

Returns (calc_two) - another_val: 2 val_num_two: 5 main_val: 100

What are some ways to approach this problem?

Comment: It's unrelated to your main question, but `AttributeError` is certainly not the right exception to be raised in the situation you're using it in. That error suggests that an attribute lookup `obj.attr` failed because `attr` doesn't exist. I think you should probably use `ValueError` instead, as that's normally raised when you pass an argument of the wrong value to a function or method. Since your decorator is checking the value you were passed against a list of allowed values, that seems most appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght !  I just looked up the definition and didn't realize that was the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object) to determine the signature, bind arguments, apply defaults, and figure out the final value of `main_val`:

```
import functools
import inspect

def main_val_decorator(f):
    f_sig = inspect.signature(f)
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        bound = f_sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        bound.apply_defaults()
        main_val = bound.arguments['main_val']

        do_whatever_with(main_val)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

This does more work than you need, because it determines bindings for all the other arguments too, but it's a lot more convenient than performing the introspection manually.

Comment: This is a little overkill - but useful nevertheless. Hoping maybe there is a more straightforward solution

Comment: I suspect this is about as easy as it gets if you want to handle a value that could be anywhere in the method signature. For a narrower situation (if the argument is keyword-only, for instance), you could come up with your own custom solution that might be simpler, but this is probably the only good general solution.

Comment: Thanks folks - there's one thing i don't quite follow, what's the point of functools.wraps in this context? Doesn't seem necessary